# Docker in virtualbox on ubuntu

Tags: docker, webserver, virtualbox

I have win 10 as an operating system, I have installed virtualbox where ubuntu is installed and docker with its containers is installed in ubuntu.
I set the virtualbox network in bridge, and in DHCP I assigned an IP that I can easily reach from the win 10 chrome browser (outside of virtualbox). The problem is that I cannot access the docker container where a webserver runs in loalhost, I can access it without problems inside the virtualbox and externally I can access another webserver in the virtualbox but not the webserver docker! How could I solve it?
thanks for any replies!

Comment: How are you starting the container?  Can you give a more specific example of how you're trying to access it, both from within the VM and from the outside host?

Comment: simply start the container with docker run -d -p 80:80 -h cartodb.localhost sverhoeven/cartodb inside the VM just type in cartodb.localhot and access the webserver!  while outside the VM with chrome browser (win10) I try to type the IP of the VM in bridge (192.168.43.100/dev/user) and access the Webserver but with errors of the page content.  That is, I can't see anything ;-)

Comment: From the comment, it seems you are trying to access the files of your container from the browser and not the webpage

Comment: What happens when you just type in your IP, 192.168.43.100

Comment: in theory docker creates a local webserver on port 80, perfectly reachable in localhost inside the VM.  I purposely added a bridge network to ensure that I get an independent ip!  I believed that using it I access the webserver docker externally from the VM!  But this does not happen!  What solutions can there be?  dive am i wrong?

Comment: however by simply typing the IP the page I see is incomplete, the debug tells me that the connection was refused, I can only see the login window without any CSS style

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have solved, I describe here the simple solution that I have adopted.
the VM has an IP assigned in dhcp by the bridge network. (this setting has remained for a second webserver to work) In virtualbox settings I simply enabled a second NAT network from "network-settings" and in "advanced-port forwarding" I only added host port on 80 and guest port on 80, because docker run establishes its ip and its port reachable only on local host (in this case reachable only inside virtualbox).